# Don't know how to fix: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java

I can't figure out what is wrong on line 34 and I need help fixing it. I don't know if I incorrectly input something or if I need to convert something.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;     

public class PaintEstimator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  double wallHeight;
  double wallWidth;
  double wallArea;
  
  System.out.println("Enter wall height (feet): ");
  wallHeight = scnr.nextDouble();
  System.out.println(wallHeight);
  wallWidth = scnr.nextDouble();                     
  System.out.println("Enter wall width (feet): ");
  System.out.println(wallWidth);
  
  
  wallArea = wallHeight * wallWidth;                        
  System.out.println("Wall area: " + (wallArea) + " square feet");     
  
  double paintNeeded;
  int cansNeeded;
  final double squareFeetPerGallons;
  final double gallonsPerCan;
  
  squareFeetPerGallons = 350.0;
  gallonsPerCan = 1.0;
  
  System.out.print("Paint needed: ");
  paintNeeded = wallArea / squareFeetPerGallons;
  System.out.print(paintNeeded);
  System.out.println(" gallons");
  cansNeeded = paintNeeded / gallonsPerCan;
  System.out.print("Cans needed: ");
  System.out.print(cansNeeded);
  System.out.println(" can(s)");
```

}
}

Comment: What's line 34?

Comment: The problematic line is `cansNeeded = paintNeeded / gallonsPerCan;`. You are dividing two doubles but assigning the result to an int. You should be casting the result of that division to int, probably after some rounding operation.

Answer (score 2):

Integers don't have decimal points, unlike doubles, which do.

You can only assign an integer to an int, not a double etc,.

In your case, you probably want to define **cansNeeded** as a double (every single other variable is a double). It should look like this:

```
double cansNeeded = paintNeeded / gallonsPerCan
```

Then you can deal with the result accordingly (round up, round down etc,.). This is more precise.

To round up, use `Math.ceil(cansNeeded)`. To round down, use `Math.floor(cansNeeded)`.

Answer (score 1):

The result of dividing doubles is a double, which can't be assigned to an int. In your case, you probably want to use `Math.ceil` and then cast to `int`.

```
cansNeeded = (int) Math.ceil(paintNeeded / gallonsPerCan);
```